# How can i add the terms of one dict to another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Let's assume i start with this dictionary:

```
mydict = {
    'a': [[2,4], [5,6]],
    'b': [[1,1], [1,7,9], [6,2,3]],
    'c': [['a'], [4,5]],
}
```

How can i append values to 'a' yet be able to add a new key if i needed to let's say 'd' what i tried is

```
plus_min_dict = {} 
plus_min_dict[key] = reference_dataset[key][line_number]
```

but it only gave one value per key apparently `=` destroyed the previous value, i want to update or append yet still be able to create a new key if it doesn't exist

**Edit:** To clarify let's assume this is my initial dictionary:

```
mydict = {
        'a': [[2,4]],}
```

i do other calculations with another dictionary let's assume it's :

```
 second_dict = {
        'a': [ [5,6]],
        'b': [[1,1], [1,7,9]],
        'c': [['a'], [4,5]],
    }
```

these calculations showed me that i have interest in [5,6] of 'a' and [1,7,9] of 'b' so i want mydict to become:

```
 mydict = {
        'a': [[2,4], [5,6]],
        'b': [[1,7,9]],  
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add the terms of a dictionary"? How would you add `[2, 4]` and `['a']`? Please show the desired output and read again [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Piinthesky edited

Comment: How does the code know, which part of the `second_dict` you are interested in?

Comment: @Piinthesky i've done the part of the code where it takes care of that.

Comment: So `second_dict` is actually `{'a': [[5,6]], 'b': [[1,7,9]]}`? Then your question should reflect this. And Michael Cara's answer generates, what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an if else loop

```
mydict = {'a': [[2,4]],}

second_dict = {
        'a': [ [5,6]],
        'b': [[1,1], [1,7,9]],
        'c': [['a'], [4,5]]}

missing_values = {
        'a': [5,6],
        'b': [1,7,9]}

for key, value in missing_values.items():
    if key in mydict:
        mydict[key ].append(value)
    else:
        mydict[key ] = [value]

print(mydict)
```

Result:

```
{'a': [[2, 4], [5, 6]], 'b': [[1, 7, 9]]}
```

Comment: Getting this in my dictionary when i print it at each key <Recursion on list with id=13983515213600>],

Comment: Please try this above example

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your question, you want to append a new value to your dictionary if the key already exists. If so, I would use a `defaultdict` for a simple reason. With a `defaultdict` you can use the method += to create (if does not exist) or add (if exist) an element :

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Your dictionaries
mydict = {
    'a': [[2,4], [5,6]],
    'b': [[1,1], [1,7,9], [6,2,3]],
    'c': [['a'], [4,5]],
}

plus_min_dict = {'a': [[3,3]]}

# d is a DefaultDict containing mydict values
d=defaultdict(list,mydict)

# d_new is a DefaultDict containing plus_min_dict dict
d_new = defaultdict(list, plus_min_dict)

# Add all key,values of d in d_new
for k, v in d.items():
    d_new[k] += d[k]

print(d_new)
```

Results :

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'c': [['a'], [4, 5]], 'a': [[3, 3], [2, 4], [5, 6]], 'b': [[1, 1], [1, 7, 9], [6, 2, 3]]})
```

Comment: That's too pin point, i want a general code as i have thousands of keys and each have hundreds of values.

Answer (score 0):

To append an item into `'a'`, you can do this:

```
mydict['a'] += ['test_item']
```

Or:

```
mydict['a'].append('test_item')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just append:

```
mydict = {
    'a': [[2,4], [5,6]],
    'b': [[1,1], [1,7,9], [6,2,3]],
    'c': [['a'], [4,5]],
}

mydict['a'].append([7,8])
mydict['d'] = [0,1]
print(mydict)
```

Comment: Kindly no pin point answers, i want a general one i can apply to my dataset.

Comment: @Talar: You have asked a question with example code and my answer applies perfectly to that code. If your real example is different you need to rephrase your question! I cannot guess how your data differs from the example.